# Confusings regarding swing program

Tags: java, swing, network-programming

I am creating a client-server chat program. I have written codes for both the server and the clients. What I want to do now is to get the list of connected users to the text area. I have a button "Get Users". But this button is not doing anything. But when I write "!getusers" from the textfield it can retrieve the list of users connected. I haven't worked with swing before. Finding it hard to spot the mistake. Here is my code

For Client:=

```
public class ChatClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
String uname;
PrintWriter pw;
BufferedReader br;
JTextArea taMessages, taUserList;
JTextField tfInput;
JButton btnSend, btnExit,btnGetUsers;
Socket client;

public ChatClient(String uname, String servername) throws Exception {
    super("Connected as: " + uname);  // set title for frame
    this.uname = uname;
    client = new Socket(servername, 9999);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    pw.println(uname);  // send name to server
    //bring up the chat interface
    buildInterface();
    new MessagesThread().start();  // create thread that listens for messages
}

public void buildInterface() {
    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnGetUsers=new JButton("Get Users");
    //chat area
    taMessages = new JTextArea();
    taMessages.setRows(10);
    taMessages.setColumns(50);
    taMessages.setEditable(false);
    //online users list
    taUserList = new JTextArea();
    taUserList.setRows(10);
    taUserList.setColumns(10);
    taUserList.setEditable(false);
    //top panel (chat area and online users list
    JScrollPane chatPanel = new JScrollPane(taMessages, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JScrollPane onlineUsersPanel = new JScrollPane(taUserList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JPanel tp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    tp.add(chatPanel);
    tp.add(onlineUsersPanel);
    add(tp, "Center");
    //user input field
    tfInput = new JTextField(50);
    //buttom panel (input field, send and exit)
    JPanel bp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    bp.add(tfInput);
    bp.add(btnSend);
    bp.add(btnExit);
    bp.add(btnGetUsers);
    add(bp, "South");
    btnSend.addActionListener(this);
    tfInput.addActionListener(this);//allow user to press Enter key in order to send message
    btnExit.addActionListener(this);
    setSize(500, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == btnExit) {
        pw.println("!end");  // send end to server so that server know about the termination
        System.exit(0);
    }else if(tfInput.getText().contains("!getusers")){
            pw.println("!getusers");
    }else if(evt.getSource()== btnGetUsers){
        pw.println("!getusers");// send get users to the server ( NOT WORKING )
    }
    else{
        // send message to server
        pw.println(tfInput.getText());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // take username from user
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name: ", "Username",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String servername = "localhost";
    try {
        new ChatClient(name, servername);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable to connect to server.\nError: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

} // end of main

// inner class for Messages Thread
class MessagesThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line;
        try {
            while (true) {
                line = br.readLine();
                taMessages.append(line + "\n");
                taMessages.setCaretPosition(taMessages.getDocument().getLength());//auto scroll to last message
            } // end of while
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    }
} //  end of client
```

For server:=

```
public class ChatServer {

    List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<HandleClient> clients = new ArrayList<HandleClient>();

    public void process() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9999);
        out.println("Server Started...");
        while (true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            //add incoming client to connected clients vector.
            HandleClient c = new HandleClient(client);
            clients.add(c);
        }  // end of while
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new ChatServer().process();
    } // end of main

    public void broadcast(String user, String message) {
        // send message to all connected users
        for (HandleClient c : clients) {
            c.sendMessage(user, message);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Inner class, responsible of handling incoming clients.
     * Each connected client will set as it's own thread.
     */
    class HandleClient extends Thread {

        String name = "";//client name/username
        BufferedReader input;//get input from client
        PrintWriter output;//send output to client

        public HandleClient(Socket client) throws Exception {
            // get input and output streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            // read name
            name = input.readLine();
            users.add(name); // add to users vector
            broadcast(name, " Has connected!");
            start();
        }

        public void sendMessage(String uname, String msg) {
            output.println(uname + ": " + msg);
        }

        public void getOnlineUsers() {

            for (HandleClient hc:clients) {
                broadcast("", hc.name);

            }
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void run() {
            String line;
            try {
                while (true) {
                    line = input.readLine();
                    if (line.equals("!end")) {
                        //notify all for user disconnection
                        broadcast(name, " Has disconnected!");
                        clients.remove(this);
                        users.remove(name);
                        break;
                    } else if (line.equals("!getusers")) {
                        getOnlineUsers();

                    }
                    broadcast(name, line); // method  of outer class - send messages to all
                } // end of while
            } // try
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } // end of run()
    } // end of inner class
} // end of Server
```

Also, I want to redirect the list of clients connected to the server on the text area "taUserList"(when I click the button "Get Users"). Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Why aren't anyone answering my questions? :O

Comment: Because people on this site prefer to answer questions, not debug other people's code.

Comment: Read here about how to post code samples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never adding any action listener to the button. So when it's clicked, nothing happens.